# Linebreak chart in pine script not plot anything

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=5
indicator("Line Break Chart")

var linebreak = 3
var current_direction = 1
var last_high = high
var last_low = low
var counter = 0

for i = 1 to 2000

    if counter == 0
        last_high := high[i]
        last_low := low[i]
    
    if current_direction == 1 and close[i] > last_high
        current_direction := -1
        last_low := close[i]
        counter := linebreak - 1
    else if current_direction == -1 and close[i] < last_low
        current_direction := 1
        last_high := close[i]
        counter := linebreak - 1
    
    counter := counter - 1
    
    if counter == 0
        if current_direction == 1
            last_high := high[i]
        else
            last_low := low[i]
     
    
plot(current_direction == 1 ? last_high : last_low, "Line Break Chart", color = current_direction == 1 ? color.green : color.red, style = plot.style_linebr)
```

i want to plot linebreak chart without using built-in function , i use this code but it plot nothing. is there any other code avalible which plot linebreak chart without using built-in function

Comment: Why do you not want to use the built-in `plot()` function?

Comment: in tradingview free version dont support built in function which is "linebreak" . so i use manual code. plot() can use

Comment: What function are you talking about? There is no `linebreak()` function in `pinescript` and `pinescript` is completely free. Are you talking about the `linebreak` chart type?

Comment: I use linebreak function but it dont plot linebreak chart , i think i have free version so tradingview not plot chart , please provide solution how i plot chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only query linebreak chart data and associate it with the bars of the current chart using `ticker.linebreak()` + `request.security()`, but you cannot create exactly the same chart in terms of the length of the linebreak bars, the scale x(time) cannot be changed.

```
//@version=5
indicator("ticker.linebreak", overlay = true) 
lbTickerid = ticker.linebreak(syminfo.tickerid, 3)
[lbOpen, lbCose] = request.security(lbTickerid, timeframe.period, [open, close], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plotcandle(lbOpen, math.max(lbOpen, lbCose), math.min(lbOpen, lbCose), lbCose, color = lbCose < lbOpen ? color.red : color.green)
```

Note: the security function call in the above example gets the most recent data and is an issue for repainting. To avoid this, remove the lookahead parameter.